# IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 add "Undo" / "Redo" etc. to the Toolbar

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, rubymine, appcode

After upgrading to 2018.3, the Undo button disappeared from Toolbar. How can I add them to the toolbar? I do know how to get **Customize toolbar** window...but I find no way of adding the *Undo* button to the toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can add Undo/Redo actions to the Toolbar like this:

[image: Undo]

[image: Toolbar]

Note that **Toolbar** needs to be enabled in the View menu:

[image: Toolbar enabled]

Comment: thanks! I have been trying to add actions while highlighting _Main toolbar_ and button for adding actions were disabled. Obviously I need to highlight _Toolbar find actions_. I wish doc. were clearer

Comment: @senseiwu you just need to highlight any item in the menu since you are choosing where the action will be added.